# Open only the first few lines of a file in Vim

Tags: vim, csv, text-files, macvim

I'm working with a CSV that's just shy of 1 GB. I want to see the the file's structure and a sample of the data, but I don't want to open the entire file. How can I load the first few rows in Vim? If it makes a difference, I'm using MacVim.

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I generally use a command like `head` or `tail` for seeing partial content of large files.

```
$head -10 <large file>
```

Comment: I'll use `head` and/or `tail` to limit the lines, then pipe to view using something like `head -1000 FILE | tail -100 | view -` to grab lines 900-1000 of a file. We occasionally get log files over 1GB so paring them down before opening them is important.

Answer (score 17):

If you must do it from vim, use this:

```
:r !head -10 path/to/big.file
```

That would get the first 10 lines of big.file and insert them into the current buffer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ vim '+%!head -10' FILE
```

What that does is open the file, then execute `:%!head -10`, which pipes the entire buffer through `head -10` and replaces the contents of the buffer with the output from `head`.

Mind the quotes, by the way.

Comment: If vim opens a 1GB file, isn't it going to take a long time before it has the buffer open so it can pipe it through head? It seems like it would be a whole lot faster to use `head -10 FILE | vim -` or do what El Isra suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only wanting to preview and not edit the file, you can just use the `less` or `more` (see comment below) command.  You can use spacebar and enter to read more of the file, and q to exit.

Comment: Originally there was an app called `more`, which is replaced on a lot of systems by [`less`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#what) now. On Mac OS, `more` actually points to `less`. They're similar, only `less` has better navigation, and can scroll backwards, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at how to do this on Windows, you can use the following in PowerShell to open the first 10 lines of a file in `gvim`:

```
PS C:\MyCSVDirectory> Get-Content .\myfile.csv -TotalCount 10 > out | gvim out
```

Personally I prefer having it opened in `gvim`, but if you'd like to have it open in terminal just use `vim` instead. Also note that this will create a file called `out` in the directory of your csv.

Alternatively you can use the following to simply print the lines in terminal:

```
PS C:\MyCSVDirectory> Get-Content .\myfile.csv -TotalCount 10
```